# Is the following sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence right?

"There's a table stands in the corner."

Comment: If you think one answer is the best for you, please marked that answer as the accepted one by clicking on the check mark below the up and down arrow. This check mark will become available two hours after you post your question.

Comment: Sounds better when spoken aloud. There would likely be the slightest hint of a syllable between "table" and "stands": "There's a table eh'stands in the corner.". Looks a bit poetic in written form, but pretty approximate to how it'd be spoken colloquially.

Answer (score 2):

It's unusual in modern speech, but you occasionally see this pattern in literature. It's as if "that" had been left out; the sentence can be understood as "There's a table [that] stands in the corner." Or you could think of "There's a table" as a way to say "that table". "That table stands in the corner."

There are many other cases where words can acceptably be left out of a sentence. A real linguist could tell you the name of this phenomenon, and its history, and other related or unrelated facts.

Comment: Perhaps the most famous example of this type is from Shakespeare (Hamlet: Act 4, Scene 7): 'There is a willow grows aslant a brook'.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, the only thing "not quite right" about OP's example is that a [relative pronoun](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/relative-pronouns) *(that, who, which,)* has been dropped.

As others have pointed out, in some cases this might be done for reasons of prosody/scansion in a "poetic" context (e.g. - Hamlet, Act IV, Scene 7: [*There is a willow grows aslant a brook*](http://www.recmusic.org/lieder/get_text.html?TextId=19190)). But in other contexts it's a perfectly natural "relaxed speech" usage...

> *"There's a man at the door [who/that] wants to speak to the lady of the house"*

Having said that, my advice to non-native speakers would be *not* to discard the relative pronoun. The usage won't always work in *either* the "poetic" or the "colloquial" register - but it usually has to be interpreted as one or the other, and if you're not already confident which way your audience will see it, there's a good chance you'll get it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No, the sentence is incorrect. It looks like it can't decide on a main verb:

> *There **is** a table **stands** in the corner.

Interestingly, the subject of both verbs is "a table." Compare the following correct sentences:

> There **is** a table.
>
> A table **stands** in the corner.

The second conveys all the information in your original incorrect sentence. There is no reason to use the preparatory subject "there" when the subject - i.e. the table - is already doing something. That is, you don't need to introduce it's mere existence (with "There is") if we understand it exists by virtue of the fact that it's standing in the corner.

However, we do sometimes introduce something's existence and give additional information, in which case we must subordinate the additional information, thus:

> There **is** a table *that stands* in the corner.

Unfortunately, that sentence sounds somewhat stilted, and I believe a much more common utterance would be:

> There **is** a table *standing* in the corner.